# Continuity at a point equivalent definitions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, let $E$ be a subset of $X$ and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Let $x_0\in X$ be an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in Y$. Prove $a.$ implies $b.$

> a. For every open set $V\subseteq Y$ which contains $L$, there exists and open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $x_0\in U$ and $F(U\cap E)\subseteq V$

> b. If we define the function $g:E\cup \{x_0\}\to Y$ by $g(x_0):= L$, and $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in E\setminus \{x_0\}$. then $g$ is continuous at $x_0$. Further if $x_0\in E$ then $f(x_0)=L$

My definition of continuity is that $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$ whenever $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$

So let $\epsilon>0$ then by $a.$ since $B_\epsilon(L)=B_\epsilon(g(x_0))\subseteq Y$ is open set, we get that there is an open set $U\subseteq X$ containing $x_0$, such that $f(U\cap E)\subseteq B_\epsilon(g(x_0))$

Since $U$ is open we know there is some $\delta>0$ such that $A=B_\delta(x_0)\subseteq U$.

Thus for all $x\in E\cap A$ we know that $f(E\cap A)\subset B_{\epsilon}(g(x_0))$

And I know that $A\cap E\neq \emptyset$ since $x_0$ is an adherent point.

Which is the same as $\forall x\in E$ if $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ then $d_Y(f(x),L)<\epsilon$

And since $g(x):=f(x)$ on $E\setminus\{x_0\}$ then we know $\forall x\in E\setminus\{x_0\}$ if $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ then $d_Y(g(x),g(x_0))<\epsilon$

And since $d_X(x_0,x_0)=0$ and $d_Y(g_{x_0},g_{x_0})=0$ we know that $d_Y(g(x),g(x_0))<\epsilon$ whenever $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ so $g$ is continuous at $x_0$

If $x_0\in E$ I want to say this line from above,

$\forall x\in E$ if $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ then $d_Y(f(x),L)<\epsilon$

Then proves $f(x_0)=L$ since $d_X(x_0,x_0)=0\delta$ always so $d_Y(f(x_0,L)<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Then $f(x_0)=L$

I don't really see where I need to use that $x_0$ is an adherent point of $E$. I know that intersection is nonempty but does it matter if it is empty? Wouldn't the statement just end up being vacuously true?

Comment: The adherent point condition is indeed unnecessary. This is trivially true when $x_0$ is not a limit point of $E$, since every function is continuous at isolated points in their domain.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok. Does my proof seem fine then? I thought I must have missed something since I didn't see the need for that condition.

Comment: I find no errors.